# Running PHP script from command line

Tags: php, apache

So I'm working with a designer on a website in PHP/MySQL and there are a few scripts that he would like to have to make life easier for him. He is pretty comfortable using the command line for stuff like git, SASS, node, etc. I would like him to be able to run my scripts like he would run a program, instead of running it through PHP.

So instead of this:

```
php /path/to/file/create_module.php module_name
```

I would like to do this:

```
myscript create_module module_name
```

Is it possible to do this with PHP on an Apache server? I know I will most likely have to modify the server to interpret it properly, which is fine. I just don't even know where to begin, and couldn't find what I needed on Google.

Comment: What is `myscript` supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would to be to create an `alias`.

So an alias of `myscript` would actually point to the command: `php /path/to/file/create_module.php` and then any extra arguments will be passed as typed.

In command line, do the following:

```
cd /etc/
nano bash.bashrc
```

At the very bottom of the file, add this line of text:

```
alias "myscript=php /path/to/file/create_module.php"
```

BASHRC is a script that is run on user login, so the alias will be recreated every time the user logs into the system.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Just a note, if you are using CentOS then the bash file is located at /etc/bashrc instead of /etc/bash.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are looking for `myscript` to do, but to run a php script via the command line without specifying the php binary, just add a a `shebang`, like

```
#!/bin/env php
<?php

// The above expects env is in /bin

$foo = "bar";
```

Or the full path if you like

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the file executable

Comment: also you have to make sure your script is path - independent.

Answer (score 1):

### Another option: Shell script wrapper

create a new text file in `/bin` or another directory in your `PATH`, name it how you would like to invoke your script and give it this content

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/your/php/scripts/folder
php script.php $*
```

don't forget to

```
chmod a+x /path/to/bash/script
```

The advantage of this is that your PHP script is run in the right directory where it may expect other resources to be that it depends on.

Answer (score 0):

On A Linux Solution:

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php
```

On a Windows Solution:

```
C:\Path\To\PHPExe C:\Path\To\phpfile.php
```